# attach function to before.jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, jstree

I'm trying to prevent deletion of the root-node in jstree. In earlier versions there was the before.jstree event, with which you could do it like this:

```
.on("before.jstree", function (e, data) {
    if(data.func === "delete_node") {
        if (data.node.type == "root_node" || true)
        {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
})
```

But since the before.jstree method has been cut in jstree 3(https://www.jstree.com/api/), this approach doesn't work anymore. Is there an alternative solution without manipulating the contextmenu event?

Comment: How are you deleting a node? Is it a context menu? Can you then hide that option if a root node is selected?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `jstree.core.check_callback` property to achieve this. This property is computed before every jstree event trigger and it expects a boolean value - `true` continues the invocation of the event handler and `false` blocks it.
You can attach a callback function for this property and make the decision based on the event triggered. In your case, if the event triggered is `delete_node` and the event target node is a root, you can return `false` to block the event.

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'check_callback' : function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
            if ((operation == "delete_node" && node.type && node.type == "root") {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @kayess: Thanks for the suggestion. Edited my answer to add an explanation.